# Computing Current from known Capacitance and Time to Charge to Known Voltage

Tags: current, capacity

If I know how long it takes to charge a capacitor of known size to a known voltage (within 10%), how do I find out the average current for that period of time?  This only needs to be approximate.

Maybe I  should ask this from another angle.

Assume a capacitor of capacity C is charging to voltage V and discharging to 0v at a rate of 5 times per second.  How do I figure out the average current or what you might call RMS current?  I don't need this to be exact -- very rough approximation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, the average current is equal to the change in charge divided by the time taken. But the change in charge is equal to the capacitance C multiplied by the change in voltage, which you know :-

$$I_{AVG}=\frac{C\cdot\Delta V}{t}$$

Your last paragraph is harder to address. The average current is not usually the same as the RMS current which will depend on the how the current varies with time. We would need to know how the charging/discharging takes place, for example constant current or through a constant resistance to a known voltage. If you are cycling the charge/discharge process, the long-term average current will of course be zero but the RMS current will be non-zero.

Comment: Maybe worth pointing out that \$C\$ is the capacitance, not the charge (which would usually be \$Q\$, by convention, to avoid clashing with \$C\$ for capacitance)

Answer (score 0):

Well, let's see if I remember circuit analysis correctly.

The circuit is this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2flc5aC.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The voltage of a capacitor is an integral of the current and the current (obviously) is a derivative of the voltage.

\$U = \frac{1}{C}\int Idt\$, \$I = C\frac{\mathrm{d} U}{\mathrm{d} t}\$

We need to stipulate the initial conditions (immediately before or after the switch is flipped. Let's say that initially the capacitor is completely discharged (its voltage is zero). When the switch is flipped, the capacitors begins to charge.

According to Kirchhoff's voltage law:

\$U=U_{R}+U_{C}\$

\$U=IR+U_{C}\$

\$U=RC\frac{\mathrm{d} U_{C}}{\mathrm{d} t}+U_{C}\$

Now we have a differential equation that can be solved using a few methods. I remember Laplace transform the best.

\$RC\frac{\mathrm{d} U_{C}}{\mathrm{d} t}+U_{C}-U=0\$

\$RC(s*U_{C}(s)-U_{C0})+U_{C}(s)-\frac{U}{s}=0\$

\$U_{C}(s)=\frac{s*RC*U_{C0}+U}{RCs^{2}+s}\$

Now we do inverse Laplace transform and get:

\$U_{C}(t)=U(1-e^{\frac{-t}{RC}})+U_{C0}e^{\frac{-t}{RC}}\$

Placing in the values from the circuit, we get:

\$U = 1, R=10^{3}, C=10^{-6}, RC=0.001, U_{C0}=0\$

\$U_{C}(t)=1(1-e^{\frac{-t}{0.001}})+0e^{\frac{-t}{0.001}}\$

\$U_{C}(t)=1(1-e^{\frac{-t}{0.001}})\$

Let's draw a graph of the voltage of the capacitor vs time:

[image: graph]

Now let's draw what the capacitor discharge curve looks like (in the formula change U to 0 and Uc0 to 1):

\$U_{C}(t)=0(1-e^{\frac{-t}{0.001}})+1e^{\frac{-t}{0.001}}\$

\$U_{C}(t)=1e^{\frac{-t}{0.001}}\$

[image: second graph]

Now, as you can see, the RC constant (called time constant) shows when the volage reaches about 37% (1/e) of the initial voltage during discharge (in the example circuit it's 1ms or 63% (1-1/e) of the final voltage during charge.

OK, during charge, when the capacitor voltage is 50% of the final voltage (in this case 0.5V, assuming initial voltage is zero):

\$t=-RC*ln(\frac{U-U_{C}}{U})\$

\$t=-0.001*ln(\frac{1-0.5}{1})=0.000693\$

Or about 0.7ms.

Now your second question:
"Assume a capacitor of capacity C is charging to voltage V and discharging to 0v at a rate of 5 times per second. How do I figure out the average current or what you might call RMS current?"

Average current is easy (see MikeJ-UK's answer). However, RMS current depends on the waveform so it may not be equal to the average current.

To calculate the current and then integrate the square of it:
\$I_{RMS}=\sqrt{\frac{1}{T2-T1}\int_{T1}^{T2} I(t)^2dt)}\$

Or if you have an array of samples (let's say you measure the current 100 times per second and now have n measurements): \$I_{RMS}=\sqrt{\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}I_{k}^2}\$

Answer (score 0):

As you have asked about "average" current calculation, and you mention the capacitor charging from zero to within 10% of the supply, cycling a full five times per second, the calculation is very simple and straightforward. However, you didn't clarify whether you were interested in calculating average Alternating Current or Direct Current, so I'll first assume that you are interested in average current drain from a DC supply source.

As already pointed out by MikeK-UK...  Iavg = (C x ΔV)/t

As you are charging the capacitor from zero to V volts well within the 1s timeframe, then a single-shot average charge current within that time is simply Mike's formula.

As you have quoted five charging cycles per second, then the calculated average DC current per second is simply the foregoing multiplied five times. This might otherwise be described as 'Half-Cycle' current.

If you were interested in the average Alternating (i.e. full-cycle) current, you must include the discharge cycle as-well, so the average alternating current will merely be twice the calculated DC current.

Answer (score -2):

Current through the capacitor will be an exponential decay as it charges up.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capacitor#DC_circuits

You can find instantaneous current if you know the initial voltage, resistance and  the time constant.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.